# Magento OnePage checkout Undefined Variable

Tags: php, magento, undefined, checkout

A few weeks ago I had a server crash, and had no real backups so everything had to be recovered manually. One of those things was a Magento store. I've got all of the files and database restored, however now when I try to go through the checkout process to test I get errors.

I can either click to register when checking out, then when I click 'Continue' on the checkout page I get a 'Loading next step' message then some kind of AJAX error in the Chrome network inspector when trying to access the saveBilling page. The error is listed below:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: nameGroupAttribute  in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Amasty/Customerattr/Model/Rewrite/Checkout/Type/Onepage.php on line 41

#0 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Amasty/Customerattr/Model/Rewrite/Checkout/Type/Onepage.php(41): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 41, Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(307): Amasty_Customerattr_Model_Rewrite_Checkout_Type_Onepage->saveBilling(Array, false)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveBillingAction()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveBilling')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/index.php(85): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

I've searched every possible combination of words that I can think of and have come up empty. This site was setup before I arrived at this company so I have no idea if anything was changed that shouldn't have been. All I know is the site was working before the server went down, and now this part doens't work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is an error being thrown from a local module (i.e. something not in magento core that we can look at `local/Amasty/Customerattr/Model/Rewrite/Checkout/Type/Onepage.php`) - you may want to post that file or explain a bit more about what it's doing here

Comment: Try turning off error logging to the screen.  It may be that this error has always been in the code, but error display setting has changed on the new server.  Add this `ini_set('display_errors', '0');` a t the top of the PHP file for a test http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: I'm actually so new to Magento that I didn't even realize it was some kind of extension rather than the core. It looks like the extension comes from a company called Amasty and the only thing I see installed by them is something called [Customer Attributes](http://amasty.com/customer-attributes.html).

Comment: I did the ini_set in both the index and the plugin file and I still get the error.

Comment: Try setting the ini on line 40 of `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Amasty/Customerattr/Model/Rewrite/Checkout/Type/Onepage.php`

Comment: ini set on line 40 just before the error and it is still produced.

However, I added 
    $nameGroupAttribute = '';
to the code outside of an if statement that was trying to do a compare with it, and I'm able to get a different error listing a different variable. Then I add that variable in the same way and checkout goes through. I'm not sure if that breaks anything though.